# Почему не меняется шрифт текста на кнопе, созданной с помощью PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qfont

Я пытался учиться создавать приложения с разделенными *GUI* и логикой. 
Для начала хотел создать только одну кнопку и изменить в ней шрифт.

На кнопке появился текст, но шрифт оказался не тем, что мне нужен.

Я делал то же самое с помощью модуля *tkinter*, проблем не возникало. Т.е. шрифт существует, с ним нет проблем, и я пишу правильное название.

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("Player")
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.choose_directory_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Choose Directory", self.centralwidget)
        self.choose_directory_button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('CeraPro-Bold', 8)) #ТУТ Я УКАЗЫВАЮ ШРИФТ
        self.choose_directory_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 100, 30))
        self.choose_directory_button.setObjectName("choose_directory_button")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("Player", "Player"))
```

**main.py**:

```
import os
import sys

import design
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Browse(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.choose_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.choose)

    def choose(self):
        dirlist = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку",".")
        print(str(dirlist))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Browse()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```py
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily('CeraPro-Bold') # сам шрифт
font.setPointSize(14) #  размер шрифта
self.choose_directory_button.setFont(font)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! С самим шрифтом я уже сам разобрался(с помощью Qt Designer), а вот его размер никак поправить не мог:)

Comment: в дизайнере также поправляется и размер, кстати, если знакомы с css, то там есть отдельная вкладка - stylesheet, там можно задать для каждого элемента свои параметры, font, background-color, цвет при нажатии и тд.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле запись

```
self.choose_directory_button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('CeraPro-Bold', 14))
```

и то что предложил @finally одно и то же.

У меня такого шрифта - нет. Проверьте, есть ли он у вас? Просто нажмите на кнопку и выберите его.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Browse(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.choose_directory_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Choose Directory", self.centralwidget)
        self.choose_directory_button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('CeraPro-Bold', 14))
        self.choose_directory_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 300, 50))        
        self.choose_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        print(self.choose_directory_button.font().family())

        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Choose Directory', self)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 60, 300, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('CeraPro-Bold')  # сам шрифт
        font.setPointSize(14)           #  размер шрифта
        self.lbl.setFont(font)
        print(self.lbl.font().family())

    def showDialog(self):
        # Здесь мы открываем диалог шрифта. 
        # Метод getFont() возвращает имя шрифта и параметр ok. 
        # Он равен True, если пользователь щелкнул Ok; в противном случае это ложь.

        font, ok = QtWidgets.QFontDialog.getFont()

        # Если мы щелкнем Ok, шрифт метки изменится с помощью setFont().
        if ok:
            self.lbl.setFont(font)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Browse()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я не часто вижу такие развернутые ответы. Шрифт, который мне нужен, отображается в окне. Но работает только ели воспользоваться советом из первого ответа. В любом случае, я нашел в вашем коде еще некоторые интересующие меня вещи:)

Comment: Я даже не думал, что можно так вызвать окно выбора шрифта